# Java FrameDemo Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, window, classpath

I'm starting to learn Java, and I am attempting to run the FrameDemo tutorial code found here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

I can compile fine with `javac FrameDemo.java` but when I try to run it with `java -cp . FrameDemo` I get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class FrameDemo`

I thought it was my classpath so I tried `java -cp D:\projects\framedemo FrameDemo` and got the same error.

Then I tried recompiling with `javac -cp . FrameDemo.java` and `javac -cp D:\projects\framedemo FrameDemo.java` and still got the same error when running `java -cp . FrameDemo` and `java -cp D:\projects\framedemo  FrameDemo`.  I also tried running `java -cp . FrameDemo.class` just for the heck of it.

Always I get `Error: Could not find or load main class FrameDemo`

What am I doing wong here?  I've just downloaded and installed the latest JDK.  The source code is exactly what is in the demo link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move all your .class files to a folder '`components`'.
Then run this:

> java components/FrameDemo

or

remove `package components;` from your source file, recompile and run :

> java FrameDemo

Comment: Thank you so much!  Am I missing something?  I don't see anywhere in the tutorial that says to put those files in a components directory.

Comment: I think its good if you can use an IDE ex: eclipse. So, it'll take care of these compiler things. Here package name means, it expects the files to be in a sub folder hierarchy.

Comment: I will definitely use an IDE soon.  I was just trying to get familiar with things before abstracting away things that I might need to know about.  Glad I hit this wall, now I know.